# Accessing filepath in Android using onActivityResult

Tags: android

I have an buttonClick on which I send some data to a mailid, but with these message I need to send an image as attachment. But I could get only imagepath in the function

```
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

which is after OnCreate method

but buttonClick comes in  `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` how can I fetch the data from onActivityResult.Looking for the reply.thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Could you post more code. and some more details.

Answer (score 1):

Make a private field variable:

```
private String mImgPath;
```

and Use it in buttonClick, such as:

```
OnCreate(){
  button.SetOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
   DoSthWithImgPath(mImgPath);
  });
}
```

Then assign value to mImgPath in onActivityResult():

```
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   mImgPath = data.getString(IMG_PATH);//Get and assign image path here.
}
```